# Use Jquery with php and html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to using Jquery. What I'm trying to achieve is to fade in any element on the page. However my header and footer are being displayed by using PHP include() am I able to use Jquery with this type of formatting? I'm unable to get anything to fadeIn().

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
   <title> <Header> </title>

enter code here
   <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

   <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#nav').fadeIn(3000);
    });

   </script>

  </head>
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Films.com</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <div id="nav">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="film.php">Film</a></li>
                <li><a href="add_film.php">Add a Film</a></li>


            </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: Something has to be hidden in order to show it. Is there CSS that you're using to do that that you forgot to post?

Answer (score 3):

the element u want to fade in needs to be hidden eg

```
 <div id="nav" style="display:none;">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="film.php">Film</a></li>
                <li><a href="add_film.php">Add a Film</a></li>


            </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: There is no CSS currently at the moment. Is this something that is needed ?

Comment: @user1829823: It's not *technically* needed, but it would be good practice to have a CSS file separate from the HTML markup instead of in-line in the element itself.

Comment: @user1829823: David is right, it is alot cleaner to have external files for likes of js/css

Answer (score 1):

> However my header and footer are being displayed by using PHP include() am I able to use Jquery with this type of formatting?

Yes.  This setup is happening server-side, before jQuery even sees it.  What your server-side PHP code is doing is emitting an HTML page to the browser.  At that point, client-side, is when the JavaScript (including jQuery) runs.  All it sees is the client-side result of the document, not how it was built server-side.

> I'm unable to get anything to fadeIn()

What you're trying to fade in with that code is already displayed.  It needs to be hidden in the first place before it can be faded into view.  You can just style it as hidden in your page's CSS:

```
#nav { display: none; }
```

What this would do is render the `#nav` element has hidden by default when the page first loads.  Then your JavaScript code would fade it in using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

**[Solved]** Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/F6mUn/1/

In order to **FadeIn** you must **hide** that respective **content**.

**Here is the Code:**

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="nav" style="display:none;">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="film.php">Film</a></li>
                <li><a href="add_film.php">Add a Film</a></li>


            </ul>

        </div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav').fadeIn(5000);
});
```